# Java program to handle different feed files

Tags: java, file

I have a requirement to write Java program where I should read daily inventory feeds from suppliers, extract the data and add to the database. The feeds are different for each supplier and only in csv, txt or excel formats. Some suppliers may have extra columns in the feed, but they all guarantee to provide one column containing the product ID and one column containing the quantity (whose column indices can vary from supplier to supplier). Each product ID appears only once in a file. Part of the problem statement is dealing with data, sometimes placed in different positions within the feed for various suppliers.
I wrote below code assuming the columns are always named “product” and “quantity”. But any suggestions on how to handle this part of problem in a better way so that it is flexible to handle continued increase in the number of suppliers and their feeds in the future?

```
package com.file.handling;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Inventory {
    private ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public Inventory(ArrayList<String> fileNames) {
        this.fileNames = fileNames;
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method that initiates file read to get data
     * @return Nothing.
     * @exception FileNotFoundException On file not found.
     * @see FileNotFoundException
     */
    public void addItems(){
        for (String filename: fileNames){
            try{
                URL url = getClass().getResource(filename);
                File myObj = new File(url.getPath());
                Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                while (myReader.hasNextLine()){
                    lines.add(myReader.nextLine());
                }
                extractData(lines, myObj.getName());
                myReader.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is a private method which extracts productID, suppleirID and Quantity values from data passed
     * @param lines arraylist of string data
     * @param filename
     * @return Nothing.
     */
    private void extractData(ArrayList<String> lines, String filename) {
//        Get fieldNames
        String fieldNameString = lines.remove(0);
        String[] fieldNames;

//        Get supplierID and file type
        String supplierID = filename.split("\\.")[0];
        String fileType = filename.split("\\.")[1];

//        Get index of fieldName product and quantity/inventory based on file type
        int productIdx = -1;
        int quantityIdx = -1;
        if (fileType.equals("csv") || filename.equals("xlsb") || fileType.equals("xls") || fileType.equals("xlsx") || fileType.equals("xlsm")){
            fieldNames = fieldNameString.split(",");
            for (int i=0; i<fieldNames.length; i++){
                String fieldName = fieldNames[i];
                if (fieldName.toLowerCase().equals("product"))
                    productIdx = i;
                else if (fieldName.toLowerCase().equals("inventory") || fieldName.toLowerCase().equals("quantity"))
                    quantityIdx = i;
            }

//            loop through remaining data to get productIDs and their quantities
            for (String line: lines){
                String productID = line.split(",")[productIdx];
                int quantity = Integer.valueOf(line.split(",")[quantityIdx]);
                System.out.println("ProductID: " + productID + " quantity: " + quantity + " SupplierID: " + supplierID);

                //                create SupplierProduct Object
                SupplierProduct supplierProduct = new SupplierProduct(supplierID, productID, quantity);

                //                WriteToDB - use supplierProduct to write to database
            }


        } else if (fileType.equals("tsv") || fileType.equals("tab")) {
            fieldNames = fieldNameString.split("\\s+");
            for (int i=0; i<fieldNames.length; i++){
                String fieldName = fieldNames[i];
                if (fieldName.toLowerCase().equals("product"))
                    productIdx = i;
                else if (fieldName.toLowerCase().equals("inventory") || fieldName.toLowerCase().equals("quantity"))
                    quantityIdx = i;
            }

//            loop through remaining data to get productIDs and their quantities
            for (String line: lines){
                String productID = line.split("\\s+")[productIdx];
                int quantity = Integer.valueOf(line.split("\\s+")[quantityIdx]);
                System.out.println("ProductID: " + productID + " Quantity: " + quantity + " SupplierID: " + supplierID);

//                create SupplierProduct Object
                SupplierProduct supplierProduct = new SupplierProduct(supplierID, productID, quantity);

//                WriteToDB - use supplierProduct to write to database

            }
        }
    }
}

class SupplierProduct {
    private String supplierID;
    private String productID;
    private int quantity;

    public SupplierProduct(String supplierID, String productID, int quantity) {
        this.supplierID = supplierID;
        this.productID = productID;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like "get (our field name) from this source's (source field access implementation)". There's a ton of ways this can be done, including using ETL tools and no code, simple string => string mapping, or defaulting to a string-string implementation unless other source-specific processing needs doing, then either subclasses or implementation lookup.

Comment: You should use the appropriate library to read a file of a certain type. For example, I use `Apache POI` to read `Excel`  files and use `Commons CSV` to read `TSV` or `CSV` files. Using these libraries should make it easy to extract the information you need.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you provide more information on how to do subclasses or implementation lookup

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input files?